# Closing questions as instances or subsets of another question?

Tags: feature-request, moderation, close-reasons

I see many AskUbuntu questions that are really too localized for the format. That's a recognized problem: we do
have a `too localized` flag, after all.

But I think many localized questions *are* worth answering at a broader
level. For example, [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/76848/24694) is
specific to the present state of an unstable PPA for a certain software
configuration; it's very localized. But the greater question—['What should I do when a PPA breaks my system'](https://askubuntu.com/q/76932/24694)—is quite useful.

Could we possibly get a feature similar to the duplicate system, but one that
links closed questions to their more general equivalents?

Comment: When a question is closed and it's a duplicate the question that the closed question is a duplicate of gets a link to the original question. What are you asking for in addition to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think that a question is too localized and you know a question that essentially answers the localized question in a more general way then vote to close the too localized question as a duplicate of the more general one.